# Callback error in asynchronous function call

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to convert an image format using the asynchronous call in Promise. I have no idea how node works but I'm not seeing why I'm getting `TypeError: callback is not a function.`. The traceback points out this error in the webp-converter module.

```
const webp = require('webp-converter');

...

.then(() => {


    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        webp.cwebp(tempLocalFilename, newLocalFilename, status =>
        {
            console.log(status);
        });
    });
  })
```

Is there anything immediately obvious here that would cause this? I wasn't sure what code to include so I can add more if needed.

Comment: `callback is not a function` You do not have `callback` anywhere in your code...? What line does it appear at? The `webp.cwebp` line?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I thought I wasn't supposed to use "callback" when using Promises? The trace points out a callback line in the `webp.cwebp` module

Comment: If the callback is in the module, does that mean it doesn't support async call?

Comment: `webp.cwebp` has parameters `(input_image, output_image, option, callback)`. You’re missing `option`. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/webp-converter#convert-other-image-format-to-webp. You can probably pass an empty string if you don’t want any options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webp-converter

When you call `webp.cwebp`, there should be *four* parameters: input (string), output (string), option (string), and callback. Try specifying some options and *then* the callback. Also, try calling `resolve` once the operation is finished, that way you can chain additional functions afterward:

```
webp.cwebp(
  tempLocalFilename,
  newLocalFilename,
  "-q 80",
  function(status) {
    console.log(status);
    if (status === '100') resolve();
    else reject();
  }
);
```